# My Spring application does not open another page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have created a Spring application using netbeans, I did not change any of configuration. In index.jsp I have a link to another page but it does not get to the second page and shows "The requested resource () is not available."

in the server console it shows the following warning

```
"WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Myapp/emp.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'"
```

my emp.jsp file is in jsp folder.

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="emp.htm">emp</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

dispatcher-servlet

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

    <bean name="/emp.htm" class="controller.Employee"/> <<I changed this to "/Myapp/emp.htm" as well but does not work

</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

Employee.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Employee implements Controller {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        logger.info("Returning hello view");

        return new ModelAndView("emp.jsp");
    }

}
```

Comment: how do you map spring servlet dispather to URLs? could you provide your web.xml? I think you need a controller taking request like /emp and then forward the request to the JSP.

Comment: @Spritiwalker, yes I am new to spring how should I do that?

Comment: @DanielMorgan : Can you please check if the `web.xml` that you posted is the correct one? It looks like you are confused with your `web.xml` and the `application-context.xml`

Comment: @DanielMorgan, Did you try changing the `<a href>` to point to the URL as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: yes it does not work, its funny that even for a  simple jsp file there are lots of configuations

Answer (score 0):

Change the `<a href>` to get the actual url like this

```
  <a href="<c:url value="/emp"/>" />
```

Also make sure that the `Dispatcher servlet` is mapped in your `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

More about Spring MVC implementation can be found [**here**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: And a controller(controller method) mapping to URL **/emp**

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by adding

`<prop key="emp.htm">empController</prop>`

and

```
<bean name="empController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="emp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel 
Yes, I can see that emp.jsp is a simple message jsp. The thing is this is how **MVC** pattern works(no thing to do with Spring). MVC is all about having a dispatcher sitting in front of all request and route the request to proper resources(e.g. controller,servlet, etc)
If the message in the jsp is dynamic generated, I reckon the request should go through a controller and forwarded to emp.jsp. If the whole point of emp.jsp is just some kinda of static page, you can put emp.js under **webapp/static/emp.jsp** and in your spring servlet configuration file indicate that everything under /static should by pass Spring **ServletDispatcher**.

The configuration file will look like this

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
```

By doing so, the request /static/emp.jsp will work and do not go through Spring DispatcherServlet.